# How to ask what OP ended up with

Tags: discussion, comments

There are often questions on SO where I would like to ask the OP what he ended up with or how he solved this problem. Since I don't have 50 reputation I can't leave a comment and I don't want to write an "answer" just to ask a question. So for example there is this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42603188/django-taggit-searching-for-posts-when-all-tags-and-title-are-contained-in-the-d) and I would like to know if she found a solution. Is there any recommended way to ask other users for beginners like me?

Comment: You'll just have to move on. If there is no answer there, the OP has either never solved it or moved on and never bothered to write an answer. Leaving such comments rarely get you a response.

Comment: Yes, moving on is currently the only option for you. When you have enough reputation, then you can either create a comment and ask (but as Marjin said, this is might won't get an answer) or you provide a bounty on the question, so you'll get an answer by someone else.

Comment: Ok thanks for the answers. There are usually multiple questions on the same topic and I always find a similar  question but sometimes I wish i could just write a message (I know SO is not a Social Network). 
It is kinda sad that those questions "die" unanswered but we just have to move on :)

Comment: mandatory [xkcd](https://xkcd.com/979/) link.

Comment: @Gimby hahahha yes that is exactly how i feel :D

Comment: Just a tip: every suggested edit you do that is accepted in review will net you +2 reputation, so that reputation handicap you currently have could be gone quite quickly with a little elbow grease...

Comment: Or just by floating around for 8 hours a day looking for questions you *can* answer. About a year ago I had a job where I got to sit on my hands a lot, so I started SOing a lot and gained ~2600 rep in a period of about 3 months (that's about 30 rep a day). Find a tag you know well and browse its unanswered questions. You'll find something you can answer. There's even badges (like Revival) for answering old questions.